# Disable maximise in jFrame and resizeable using mouse

Tags: java, swing, jframe

`JFrame` with hidden or no maximize button but should be able to re-size using mouse(clicking and dragging on `jFrame` border). `setResizable(false)` is only disabling the minimize button but not able to re-size using mouse.

Comment: Unless you write your own window UI delegate, this is not possible in native Java

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065032/swing-resizing-a-jframe-like-frames-in-linux-e-g/13067244#13067244) similar answer

Answer (score 2):

I personally can't think of a reason to allow resize and not allow maximize but here is an example of how to prevent maximizing a JFrame while still allowing resize and minimize.  Tested in windows, untested on all other platforms.  Full screen flash is minimized using setMaximizedBounds().

```
    final JFrame jFrameNoMax = new JFrame() {
        {
            setMaximizedBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0));
            addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
                public void windowStateChanged(final WindowEvent e) {
                    if (e.getNewState() == MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                        setExtendedState(NORMAL);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    // Tester
    jFrameNoMax.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrameNoMax.setSize(300, 300);
    jFrameNoMax.setLocation(300, 300);
    jFrameNoMax.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: its OK in windows, and sorry to tell it can be maximize in  mac

Answer (score 2):

You can take the following steps:

-Right click on JFrame
-Select properties
-Uncheck the resizable checkbox
-Close properties
-Run the program

See the attached illustration:
[image: Freeze maximize button]

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use a `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`. This allows the window to be manually resizeable but not maximizeable. The only problem with doing this is that you lose both the minimize and maximize buttons. This may or may not be a problem for your application.

Comment: Sorry I also need to minimize the window.