# Adding onResizeListener to JButton

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe, jbutton

I have a window(`JFrame`) which contains special types of `JButtons` (my own class of buttons which extend `JButton`). That window suppose to resize itself when the button size is changing(in example when I click on the button its font size increases and the whole size of JButton too).

I do not want make `JFrame` fit the buttons, but let me decide how big the window should be, so `pack()` is no solution.

I was thinking about a kind of component listner which would resize window on button size change but I could not find anything.

[image]

**Code example(working, click the button):**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ResizingButton extends JButton {
    public ResizingButton(String txt) {
        super();
        setText(txt);
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
                int newFontSize = getFont().getSize() + 1;
                setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, newFontSize));
                FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
                int width = metrics.stringWidth(getText());
                int height = metrics.getHeight();
                Dimension newDimension = new Dimension(width + 40, height + 10);
                setPreferredSize(newDimension);
                setBounds(new Rectangle(getLocation(), getPreferredSize()));
            }


    });
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Zadanie2 extends JFrame {
    JButton jb1, jb2;
    public Zadanie2() {
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setSize(200, 80);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(new ResizingButton("tekst"));
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Zadanie2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That window suppose to resize itself when the button size is changing(in example when I click on the button its font size increases and the whole size of JButton too).

Override the getPreferredSize() of your custom button.

> I do not want make JFrame fit the buttons, but let me decide how big the window should be, so pack() is no solution.

Now when you invoke pack() the frame will be resized taking into account the new preferred size of the button.

> I was thinking about a kind of component listner which would resize window on button size change but I could not find anything.

The `ComponentListener` has a `componentResized()` event. So you would add the listener to the button. You would only use this approach if your automatic resizing code is different then just using pack().

Comment: I stated that I am not asking about the `pack()`, but thank You.

Comment: I know, but using the approach I suggest the pack() does not control the size of the button. The pack() controls the size of the frame based on the preferred size of the button. I wasn't sure I understood your requirement. Maybe you want to allow extra space around the button. In this case you should use a panel with an EmptyBorder so you don't need to manually keep calculating the frame size. The point of my answer is that you should always avoid doing manual size calcualations and let Swing handle it.

Answer (score 1):

- see [`ComponentListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13065148/714968)
- `ComponentListener` firing one event per one pixel on resize
- add `Swing Timer` if event to the Swing GUI will be done only once time, if resize ended
- `Swing Timer` with small dealy 350-500ms, if resize still continue then to test `Timer.isRunning`, if return true then only `Timer#restart()`,