# Java - How to make componentResized event only trigger once?

Tags: java, jframe, resize, window-resize, componentlistener

I have a program with a few buttons images and labels. When the window get resized all the componetnts get resized too. But the problem is when the window get resized it triggers multiple events, around 50-200 or more. Because resizing images and so on takes a bit of time I only want the last created evrnt to update the screen.

I'm open to other ideas and plans too!

//Jesper

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338322/getting-the-last-resize-event-of-a-component. (If I understand what you're asking for correctly, then the `Timer` solution mentioned there is the only way that I know of.)

Comment: Thank you! I tried to find the same question on google and here but didn't find it! It fixed my problems totaly!